# Smooth scroll on button click: Not working for me but works great in the Code Snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and jQuery. My css and JavaScript codes are external to html file. There are already answers for this question and i tried, tried all the codes but scrolling does not work. I don't know what i missed. jQuery is installed (Even CDN).
Well, this code works in the snippet so probably something wrong with javaScript or JQuery. Still i don't know what is my mistake. Please help.

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#fir").offset().top},
        'slow');
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#sec").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

```css
.button1{ position:absolute; top:130px; left:150px; font-size: 10px; cursor:pointer; color:#000000;}
.main{ width: 100%; height:500px; background:black; }
.first{ width: 100%; height: 1000px; background: green; }
.second{ width: 100%; height: 1000px; background: blue; }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
    </head>

    <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script> <!-- JQuery CDN -->
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="JQuery.js"><\/script>');</script>  <!-- JQuery library -->
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- my javascript -->

    <div class="main">
    <button id="btn1" type="button" class="button1">Sign Up</button>
    <button id="btn2" type="button" class="button1" style=left:250px>Sign In</button></div>
    <div id="fir" class="first"></div>
    <div id="sec" class="second"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: in this case as you can see from the snippet everything is fine with your code. I advice you checking it with different browsers to broaden vision of an issue.

Comment: Yes, i already did that and it doesn't work. JavaScript works fine. Checked with  $(function() {  alert();   });

Comment: try 2000 value speed in place of slow in scrollTop.

Comment: Tried. There is no problem with the code because i tried all the way to alter the code and run it. I even tried the codes suggested by others also from other forum. The code works fine for everyone. I'm dealing with something else.

Comment: do you wrap your custom JS (in the external file) in $(document).ready() function ? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: That worked. As a beginner I did not know about that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have combined (for simplicity of my test) all the elements into singe .html file with some modifications and it works for me:

- move `script` tags at the end of the document
- add `document.ready()` logic

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .button1{ position:absolute; top:130px; left:150px; font-size: 10px; cursor:pointer; color:#000000;}
    .main{ width: 100%; height:500px; background:black; }
    .first{ width: 100%; height: 1000px; background: green; }
    .second{ width: 100%; height: 1000px; background: blue; }
</style>
<div class="main">
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="button1">Sign Up</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" class="button1" style=left:250px>Sign In</button></div>
<div id="fir" class="first"></div>
<div id="sec" class="second"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script> <!-- JQuery CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#btn1").click(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#fir").offset().top},
                'slow');
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#sec").offset().top},
                'slow');
        });        
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. But One question, is it an appropriate way to put it at the end or that's a standard?

Comment: I don't know if it's still valid (especially in latest browsers), but in good old days page rendering was blocked while loading and executing scripts on page and even worse scripts where loaded and executed in a serial manner - to the case for today's browsers.

Comment: 1 more question please help. For the same code that i have posted above i have a form and submit button at the end. When i click submit the scroll goes back to top. How to maintain it to the same position on refresh or posting data...